# Populate form with values from the database in Codeigniter

Tags: forms, codeigniter

Is there a Codeigniter way of populating a form with data from the database? For example, if the user edits a previously saved form. Since it's previously saved then existing data already exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't any direct way of loading data from the database into your forms. BUT:

- You can use the template parse library:
  http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/parser.html

  You only have to load the data into an array and then the labels into
  the form.
- Or you can use the `set_value()` function, that has a second parameter(optional) that gives the field of a form a default value(very useful editing forms) 
  http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#helperreference
- Also I'm now working in a third party addon that loads and makes forms automatically, but it's very alpha to use it, but, there is rabbit forms that makes more or less the same(search for it in google, "rabbit forms codeigniter", can't post the hyperlink due to low reputation.

Comment: I got it to work by using `set_value()` and several ternary operators. I just had to follow a series of steps, mainly: Check if any values exist; get those values or use defaults; and finally plug in values after running them through ternary operators.